# php header location not working in my vps

Tags: php

I have recently upgraded from shared hosting to vps.

In my php script, I have a header redirect like follows:

```
header("Location: index.php?success");
```

The problem is, it successfully redirects to index.php but the

```
?success
```

at the end of index.php is missing.

I'm pretty sure my code is correct because the same script worked well in a shared hosting.

So an help ???

Do i have to make any changes to my vps ???

Comment: do you get any kind of error? and paste your code.. with this little info its difficult to tell anything

Answer (score 1):

HTTP `Location` headers must be absolute paths according to [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30).

Comment: not working for absolute urls too.

BTW both absolute and relative urls are working in a shared hosting.

Comment: Whether relative URLs are working or not does not rally matter, as they *must* be absolute. Try to use `success=1` or something, maybe empty variables get filtered by the PHP (settings) of the vps...

Comment: no that too not working.
if i get a chance to change the settings, what exactly should i change ???

Comment: Last idea that I could think of: Do you use `$_GET['success']` (or something similar) or just `$success`? Support for the latter is turned off by in the settings by default (and should not be used!)